# Difference between function composition operator (.) and fmap (<$>)

Tags: haskell, operators, functor, function-composition

Currently reading through [this article](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) (which is pretty brilliant btw) and have a pretty simple question:

If I combine two functions like `(+3)` and `(+2)` with `<$>`, it seems to give me a new function that adds 5 to whatever is passed to it. If I do the same with the function composition operator, i.e. `(+3) . (+2)`, would it not do the same thing? If that is true, is there a relationship here between these two operators such that they do the same thing in this simple case?

Is this even an intelligent question?

Comment: Check out http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids and search for "Another instance of Functor that we've been dealing with all along but didn't know was a Functor is (->) r."

Comment: As a side note, the type that everyone is spelling `(->) r` might be more intuitively rendered as `(r ->)`, so if `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` then when `f` is `(r ->)`, you get `(.) :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`.

Comment: They are exactly the same, but `fmap` and `<$>` work polymorphically on any functor.

Comment: The short version: `(<$>) = fmap`, the `fmap` instance for functions happens to be `(.)`. Regarding functions there are no differences whatsoever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functions `fmap` and `<$>` both have the same type:

```
> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> :t (<$>)
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

While the function `.` is

```
> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So how is it possible that we can use `fmap` on a function and end up with `.`? I'm assuming you understand what a Functor is, so now you have to understand that "functions" are Functors. How so?

```
> :i (->)
data (->) a b   -- Defined in `GHC.Prim'
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
```

Unlike `Just`, `[]` and `Left`, functions do not have a constructor that can be used. The Functor instance is applied to the syntax itself. We can see from :info in ghci that the syntactic arrow `->` actually has an instance for functor.

What happens when we look at the type of +3?

```
> :t (+3)
(+3) :: Num a => a -> a
```

So the function (+3) is a Functor that accepts an a and returns an a. When we use `fmap` on a Functor and that also gives us back a Functor, we get nested Functors:

```
> :t fmap Just (Just 3)
fmap Just (Just 3) :: Num a => Maybe (Maybe a)
> :t fmap (replicate 5) [1,2,3]
fmap (replicate 5) [1,2,3] :: Num a => [[a]]
```

Likewise, when we apply `fmap` to two functions we get a function inside a function. The only difference is that they are fused together:

```
> :t (fmap (+3) (+2))
(fmap (+3) (+2)) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Why doesn't this result in the type `(->) (->) a a`? We have to remember that the first argument of `fmap` is a function `(a -> b)` and **not necessarily** a Functor. So when we do `fmap g (Just 5)` we can have any transformation. But whenever we perform `fmap` on a function we know that it will **always** result with a function inside of a function.

Thus `fmap (+3) (+2)` evaluates to something like this: `\x -> (\x' -> x' + 3) (x + 2)`. That is a really roundabout way of writing `(+3) . (+2)`.

```
> :t (fmap (+3) (+2))
(fmap (+3) (+2)) :: Num a => a -> a
> :t ((.) (+3) (+2))
((.) (+3) (+2)) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Normally to get around the concat problem `(Maybe (Maybe a))` or `[[a]]` we actually need to rely on it being a `Monad a`, so that we can use a bind `>>=`. But functions `(->)` are a special case because we know that every single time we use `fmap` on a function, it will always give us a function in side of a function. This cannot be said for any other Functor except `->`. As such we can be sure to always concatenate `fmap` on functions.

Therefore any `f <$> g == f . g`

Edit: A quick side note, if you do this `fmap (+) (+0)` you end up with a function inside a function. In this case the monadic bind (`>>=`) is actually needed to concatenate the functions:

```
> :t fmap (+) (+0)
fmap (+) (+0) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
> :t (+0) >>= (+)
(+0) >>= (+) :: Num b => b -> b
> let bindfunc = (+0) >>= (+)
> bindfunc 5
10
```

Which is not entirely unlike the behaviour we get when we do `[1,2] >>= replicate 5`:

```
> [1,2] >>= replicate 5
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Comment: I find the statement "`fmap (+3) (+2)` evaluates to `\x->(\x' -> x'+3) (x+2)`" misleading: for functions, `fmap=(.)`, so `fmap (+3) (+2)` evaluates precisely to `(+3) . (+2)`.

Comment: @crockeea well, `\x->(\x' -> x'+3) (x+2) == \x->(+3) ( (+2) x ) == (+3) . (+2)` so it's confusing, but not misleading.

Answer (score 8):

To find information about the `Functor` instance for functions, match up the types to find the relevant instance:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Then here `a ~ Int`, `b ~ Int` and `f ~ (->) Int`.

You can see all of the `Functor` instances that come with GHC [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-). `(->)` is just an infix type operator with two type parameters. We usually see it applied as `Int -> Int`, but this is equivalent to `(->) Int Int`. 
There is a `Functor` instance for the (partially applied) type `(->) r` (for any type `r::*`).

Looking at the [`((->) r)` instance for `Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-65), we see that `fmap = (.)`, so there is no practical difference between `(+3) . (+2)` and `fmap (+3) (+2)` (same as `(+3) <$> (+2)`.

Comment: It seems to me that some mention should be made of another generalization of `(.)`, from `Control.Category`. Also of the advantages of using a non-generalized version.

Comment: I understand the gist of your reply; I'm quite new to Haskell and I'm unsure what you mean by the "`((->) r)` instance for `Functor`".

Comment: Actually, there are a lot of instances that come with GHC that aren't on that list. That only shows the instances in `base`, so it doesn't include the ones in `array`, `vector`, `containers`, `transformers`, `mtl`, etc.

Comment: I usually call it "the `Functor` instance for `((->) r)`." If you follow Eric's link, you probably have to scroll down a little bit to find it. In its entirety, it is `instance Functor ((->) r) where { fmap = (.) }`. The LYAH chapter dfeuer linked in a comment to your question will probably help you understand.