# How to implement a functor so that map can be applied to two functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, functor

In Haskell you can apply `fmap` to two functions, which is basically function composition. You can even compose `fmap` to enable function composition of functions with higher arity (`fmap . fmap`).

This works because functions are functors.

How would such a functor (or the appropriate `map` method) be implemented in Javascript?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
funcProto = {
  map(f) { return y => f(this.x(y)) }
};

function func(x) {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(funcProto), {x: x});
}

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const map = f => ftor => ftor.map(f);
const sub = y => x => x - y;
const sqr = x => x * x;
const inc = x => x + 1;
```

This works for normal function composition:

```
func(sqr).map(inc)(2); // 5
```

However, it doesn't work for a composed version of `map`:

```
const map2 = comp(map)(map);
map2(sub)(sub)(10)(5)(4); // Error
```

I think I adapt myself too much to the traditional way functors are implemented in Javascript. Functions as functors behave differently from list or maybe.

Comment: "*the traditional way functors are implemented in Javascript*" - there is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell, everything is a function. In your javascript, some of your functions are represented as `func`s with an `.x()` method, and some are native `Function`s. That cannot work.

Here are three approaches:

```
const sub = y => x => x - y;
const sqr = x => x * x;
const inc = x => x + 1;
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
```

- plain functions, no methods.

  ```
  const fmap = comp; // for functions only
  console.log(fmap(inc)(sqr)(1)) // 5
  const fmap2 = comp(fmap)(fmap);
  console.log(fmap2(sub)(sub)(10)(5)(4)); // 9
  ```
- extending native `Function`s, using `fmap` as  a method:

  ```
  Function.prototype.fmap = function(f) { return comp(this)(f); };
  console.log(sqr.fmap(inc)(1)); // 5
  const fmap2 = comp.fmap(comp) // not exactly what you want, works just like above
  Function.prototype.fmap2 = function(f) { return this.fmap(g => g.fmap(f)); } // better
  console.log(sub.fmap2(sub)(10)(5)(4)); // 9
  ```
- building your own function type (also in ES6):

  ```
  function Func(f) {
      if (!new.target) return new Func(f);
      this.call = f;
  }
  // Ahem.
  const sub = Func(y => Func(x => x - y));
  const sqr = Func(x => x * x);
  const inc = Func(x => x + 1);
  const comp = Func(f => Func(g => Func(x => f.call(g.call(x)))));
  // Now let's start
  const fmap = Func(f => Func(x => x.fmap(f))); // a typeclass!
  Func.prototype.fmap = function(f) { return comp(this)(f); }; // an instance of the class!
  console.log(fmap.call(inc).call(sqr).call(1)); // 5
  const fmap2 = comp.call(fmap).call(fmap);
  console.log(fmap2.call(sub).call(sub).call(10).call(5).call(4)); // 9
  ```

Comment: `const fmap = comp;` is very humorous, question answered. Seriously, `fmap` and `(.)` have different types in Haskell, so I wondered why they are equivalent (provided fmap is applied to two functions). And you just say `fmap === comp`, deal with it. OK then, there is no practical difference between `fmap` and `comp` in this context and it makes probably little sense to build a `comp` version for methods in Javascript. I asked this question originally to obtain a deeper understanding of `fmap` and functors and the fact that functions are functors.

Comment: Since `fmap` is a method in the `Functor` type class, it is defined for various instances of `Functor` (such as lists, for example), of which functions are just one.  That's why `fmap` has a different (more general) type than `.`.  For functions, `fmap` indeed coincides with `.`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-638

(Sorry I was confused in my previous comment, which is already deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm mistaken but you seem to be confused about `Functor`s in Haskell.  The `Functor` type class in Haskell represents data types on which "map" (`fmap` to be more precise) is defined:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html

For instance, lists (`[]` in Haskell) are an instance of `Functor`, like:

```
    fmap (\x->x+1) [1,2,3]   -- returns [2,3,4]
```

As specified in the documentation above, it is true that `fmap (f . g)` should be equivalent to `fmap f . fmap g` (recall that `.` in Haskell means function composition, that is, `(f.g) x` equals `f(g(x))`).  For instance, let

```
    f x = x + 1
```

and:

```
    g y = y * 2
```

Then

```
    fmap (f.g) [1,2,3]   -- equivalent to [(f.g) 1, (f.g) 2, (f.g) 3]
```

and

```
    (fmap f . fmap g) [1,2,3]   -- equivalent to (fmap f (fmap g [1,2,3]))
```

are equivalent and both return `[3,5,7]`.

`Array`s in JavaScript are already a `Functor` in this sense since they have `map`.

```
    const f = x => x + 1;
    const g = y => y * 2;
    const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
    const fmap_array = f => a => a.map(f);

    fmap_array (comp(f)(g)) ([1,2,3]); // [3,5,7]
    (comp (fmap_array(f)) (fmap_array(g))) ([1,2,3]); // [3,5,7]
```

Or, you can do this if you like:

```
    Array.prototype.fmap = function(f) { return this.map(f); }
    [1,2,3].fmap(f); // [2,3,4]
    [1,2,3].fmap(g); // [2,4,6]
    [1,2,3].fmap(comp(f)(g)); // [3,5,7]
    [1,2,3].fmap(g).fmap(f); // [3,5,7]
```

P.S.

Now I see what you meant in your question - functions (`->` in Haskell) are also an instance of `Functor`, indeed defined as function composition `fmap f g = (f . g)`:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#control.i:ic:Functor:Functor:28

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-638

For something similar in JavaScript,

```
    const fmap_func = f => g => comp(f)(g); // or "const fmap_func = comp;"!
    fmap_func(f)(g)(42); // 85
```

or, again if you like:

```
    Function.prototype.fmap = function(f) { return comp(f)(this); };
    g.fmap(f)(42); // 85
```

Comment: When you combine two functions with `fmap` in Haskell you get the same result as with `(.)` ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883414/difference-between-function-composition-operator-and-fmap)). And if you compose it (`fmap . fmap`) it behaves like `(.).(.)` ([see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5822395)). To better understand the why I tried to implement such an `fmap` in Javascript. But it turned out that this makes no sense, because `fmap` (combined with two functions) and `comp` are practically the same in Javascript.

Comment: Got it now - I've added a P.S.