# Explanation of <$> and <*> when used with functions

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell currently and I am having a really hard  time wrapping my head around how to explain `<$>` and `<*>`'s behavior.

For some context this all came from searching how to use an `or` operation when using `takeWhile` and the answer I found was this

```
takeWhile ((||) <$> isDigit <*> (=='.'))
```

In most of the documentation I have seen, `<*>` is used with a container type.

```
show <*> Maybe 10
```

By looking at

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

It tells me that <*> keeps the outer container if its contents and applies the right to the inside, then wraps it back into the container

```
   a       b          f       a        f       b
([Int] -> String) -> [Just]([Int]) -> [Just]([String])
```

This makes sense to me, in my mind the `f a` is essentially happening inside the container, but when I try the same logic, I can make sense to me but I cant correlate the logic

```
f = (+) <$> (read)
```

so for `f` it becomes

```
   a           b              f           a          f            b
([Int] -> [Int -> Int]) -> ([String] -> [Int]) -> ([String] -> [Int -> Int])
```

So `f` being the container really confuses me when I try and work out what this code is going to do. I understand when I write it out like this, I can work it out and see its basically equivalent to the `.`

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

  b           c               a           b          a            c
([Int] -> [Int -> Int]) -> ([String] -> [Int]) -> ([String] -> [Int -> Int])
```

so it can be written as

```
f = (+) . read
```

Why not just write it as just that? Why wasn't the original snippet just written as

```
takeWhile ((||) . isDigit <*> (=='.'))
```

or does `<$>` imply something in this context that `.` des not?

---

Now looking at `<*>`, it seems like it is basicly exactly the same as the <$> except it takes two containers, uses the inner of both, then puts it pack in the container

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

so

```
Just show <*> Just 10

   f      a         b           f       a             f     b
[Just]([Int->Int]->[Int]) -> [Just]([Int->Int]) -> [Just]([Int])
```

However with functions, it becomes murky how things are being passed around to each other.
Looking at the original snippit and breaking it up

```
f1 :: Char -> Bool -> Bool
f1 = (||) . isDigit 

f2 :: Char -> Bool
f2 = f1 <*> (== '.')
```

`<*>` behavior in `f2` is

```
   f        a          b          f          a           f       b
([Char] -> [Bool] -> [Bool]) -> ([Char] -> [Bool]) -> ([Char] -> [Bool])
```

So using previous logic, I see it as `Char ->` is the container, but its not very useful for me when working out what's happening.

It looks to me as if `<*>` is passing the function parameter into right side, then passing the same function parameter, and the return value into the left?
So to me, it looks equivalent to

```
f2 :: Char -> Bool
f2 x = f1 x (x=='_')
```

Its a bit of mental gymnastics for me to work out where the data is flowing when I see `<*>` and `<$>`. I guess im just looking for how an experienced haskell-er would read these operations in their head.

Comment: Difference between . and <$> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883414/difference-between-function-composition-operator-and-fmap/27883814

Also read functor and applicative sections from typeclassopedia https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia

Comment: These `f`s in the types correspond to instances of the type classes [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor) (in the case of `<$>`) and [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) (in the case of `<*>`). Those links have instance lists. Examples of instances of these would be `Maybe` and `[]` and `Either a`. Now, the instance that is confusing here is `(->) r`. Note that `(->) r b` is the same as `r -> b`, so `(->) r` could be read as `(r ->)` (although this syntax is not allowed in Haskell)

Comment: On functions, there _is_ no difference between `.` and `<$>`.  As to the gymnastics, after having worked out why it is that way, you just memorize `(f <*> g) x = f x $ g x`. And ``(h <$> f <*> g) x = (liftA2 h f g) x = f x `h` g x = (h . f) x (g x)``.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate - the question was about something much more specific - I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54961639/applicative-functor-evaluation-is-not-clear-to-me/54962496#54962496) previous answer of mine might be helpful to you. No worries if it isn't!

Comment: Just a comment. For every Applicative functor the following expresion `f <$> x <*> y` is equivalent to `liftA2 f x y`. Turns out that `liftA2` for function instance is very handy and woth to learn. Essentially  `liftA2 c f g ==\x -> c (f x) (g x)`. For example `(||) <$> isDigit <*> (=='.') == liftA2 (||) isDigit (== '.') == \x -> isDigit x || x == '.'`

Comment: A function is a container. It contains values indexed by the parameter.

Comment: @Ammar by "differences [in that link]" you mean, "_no_ differences [as shown in that link]".

Comment: As for “how an experienced haskell-er would read these operations”, I see `(||) <$> isDigit <*> (== '.')` as “is digit or equals dot”. This is essentially the same thing as `\ c -> isDigit c || c == '.'`, but without needing to worry about the variable. `f <$> g <*> h` or `liftA2 f g h` is just plumbing; the actual content is `isDigit`, `(== '.')`, and `||`, which tell me that I’m using some implicit `Char ->` context to produce a `Bool`. It could also be spelled `isDigit <||> (== '.')` using `(<||>) = liftA2 (||)` (or `x <||> y = x >>= \ case { True -> pure True; _ -> y }` for `Monad`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The applicative instance for functions is quite simple:

```
f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
```

You can verify for yourself that the types match up. And as you said,

```
(<$>) = (.)
```

(Ignoring fixity)

So you can rewrite your function:

```
(||) <$> isDigit <*> (=='.')
(||) . isDigit   <*> (=='.')
\x -> ((||) . isDigit) x ((=='.') x)

-- Which can simply be rewritten as:
\x -> isDigit x || x == '.'
```

---

But it's important to understand why the function instance is as it is and how it works. Let's begin with `Maybe`:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure :: a -> Maybe a
    pure x = Just x

    (<*>) :: Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b    
    Nothing  <*> _        = Nothing
    _        <*> Nothing  = Nothing
    (Just f) <*> (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

Ignore the implementation here and just look at the types. First, notice that we've made `Maybe` an instance of `Applicative`. What exactly *is* `Maybe`? You might say that it's a type, but that isn't true - I can't write something like

```
x :: Maybe
```

- that doesn't make sense. Instead, I need to write

```
x :: Maybe Int
-- Or
x :: Maybe Char
```

or any other type after `Maybe`. So we give `Maybe` a type like `Int` or `Char`, and it suddenly becomes a type itself! That's why `Maybe` is what's known as a type constructor.
And that's exactly what the `Applicative` typeclass expects - a type constructor, which you can put any other type inside. So, using your analogy, we can think of giving `Applicative` a container type.

Now, what do I mean by

```
a -> b
```

?

We can rewrite it using prefix notation (the same way `1 + 2 = (+) 1 2`)

```
(->) a b
```

And here we see that the arrow `(->)` itself is also just a type constructor - but unlike `Maybe`, it takes **two** types. But `Applicative` only wants a type constructor which takes one type. So we give it this:

```
instance Applicative ((->) r)
```

Which means that for any `r`, `(->) r` is an `Applicative`. Continuing the container analogy, `(->) r` is now a container for any type `b` such that the resulting type is `r -> b`. What that means is that the *contained* type is actually the **future result** of the function on giving it an `r`.

Now for the actual instance:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Substituting `(->) r` as the applicative,

```
(<*>) :: ((->) r (a -> b)) -> ((->) r a) ((->) r b)
-- Rewriting it in infix notation:
(<*>) :: (r -> (a -> b)) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

How would we go about writing the instance? Well, we need a way to get the contained type out of the container - but we can't use pattern matching like we did with `Maybe`. So, we use a lambda:

```
(f :: r -> (a -> b)) <*> (g :: r -> a) = \(x :: r) -> f x (g x)
```

And the type of `f x (g x)` is `b`, so the entire lambda has type `r -> b`, which is exactly what we were looking for!

**EDIT**: I noticed that I didn't talk about the implementation of `pure` for functions - I could update the answer, but try seeing if you can use the type signature to work it out yourself!